# Android Activity being recreate when the starting next activity with different screen orientation

Tags: android

I found that when we change the orientation of current activity by screen rotation, the previous activity will be recreated in background.

What I'm trying to say is, for example:

I had set the screen orientation for both activity in the manifest file

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="package.PotraitActivity"></activity>
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name="package.MyActivity"></activity>
```

In PotraitActivity.java,

```
Button mybutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) 
  {  Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

When clicked on myButton, LandscapeActivity was been started. But at the same time OnCreate() method in PotraitActivity was called as well.

I found the same thing happened when:

1. the screen orientation for both activities is different or
2. Screen rotation is enabled for MyActivity (screenOrientation="user"). OnCreate() method in PotraitActivity is called every time we rotated MyActivity.

Anyone has idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your **package.PotraitActivity** activity in manifest. Setting this will ignore the default screen orientation implementation and will give you the control to override it manually.

Comment: this happened even though i had set android:configChanges="orientation"... anyway thanks for your comment =)

Comment: Oops sorry Waqas.... I had tried to add android:configChanges="orientation" to package.PotraitActivity and it is works!!! can you explain further why it woking this way?

Comment: setting this tells the framework that in case the orientation gets changed, you'll handle it manually in your code (load new layout-if any)

Answer (score 1):

Call finish() inthe onclick function of the button.

```
 Button mybutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) 
  {  Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
  }
});
```

Thanks...

Comment: i had tried and it is work. Do you have any idea on why the activity keep on recreated without calling finish()? As I know OnCreate method will only called when the activity first created. Anyhow thanks for your answer. It is pretty helpful to me =)

Comment: OnCreate method will only called when the activity first created.when we go to another screen it Pausesand when we call it again this Resumes it. But if we call finish() then the activity distroys and start it again. Thanks, If my answer is helped you pls vote for me..

Answer (score 0):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

better to set orientation in oncreate() and also in manifeast file add this line for both activity

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar situation recently, which is really frustrating. So I decide to write my solution here, though it is an old question.

There are two activity, activity A and activity B. Activity A is a normal activity with portrait orientation, while activity B used for displaying videos is in landscape orientation.

Strange Things happen when activity A starts Activity B. Activity A recreates itself every time it starts Activity B.

However, I write a similar demo which these things don't happen.

I doubt what's the difference and find this line in the styles.xml of the original project.

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

So I delete this line and restart the project again. Every thing back to normal again.

Here's my guess:
The SurfaceView in activity B will punch a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed. Plus the `android:windowIsTranslucent` attribute, the system judges the previous activity is visible and recreate it again.

Solution:
Just delete `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`.